# How can I use Onaction VBA command without knowing sheet name?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the following macro to assign vba code to a shape.

When using the code I get Runtime Error 438 "Object doesnt support this property or method"

My sheet number always changes, so i cannot hard code it to the code below.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub assignCodeToShape()
Dim x As Integer
x = getSheetNumber
ActiveSheet.Shapes("fileShape").OnAction = Sheets(x) & ".CommandButton1_Click"
End Sub

Function getSheetNumber as Integer()
    getSheetNumber =ActiveSheet.Index
End Function
```

Comment: Do you mean `Sheets(x).Name`? Though this all can be simplified.

Comment: @BigBen how can I get the Sheet Number, not Sheet Name or Sheet Index?
Ex: Sheet5("mySheet") I want Sheet5 to appear, not mySheet

Comment: See the posted answer and ignore my comment.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Shapes("fileShape").OnAction = .CodeName & ".CommandButton1_Click"
End With
```